# React customize Material-UI Icons styles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a React.js app with Typescript. I want to disable visited Material Icons coloring on an anchor tag and I have the following stylesheet.

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles(
    myAnchor: {
      "&:visited": {color: "inherit"},
      "&:hover": {color: "inherit"},
      "&:active": {color: "inherit"}
    }
    ...
  )
  const classes = useStyles();
```

But it did not work when I did `<a className={classes.myAnchor}><FacebookIcon /></a>`. Did I get anything wrong with `"&:visited"`?

Comment: @keikai there is no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Material-UI **IconButtn**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import FacebookIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Facebook";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  icon: {
    "& :visited": { color: "red" },
    "& :hover": { color: "red" },
    "& :active": { color: "red" }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IconButton
        className={classes.icon}
        // component={Link}
        // to={`/url`}
      >
        <FacebookIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: that did not work but whats the difference between those?

Comment: @tbraden Could you be more specific on what not work?

Comment: it suddenly came across my mind that it might be a problem related to materialui icons that I am using, i will update the question

Comment: I think what actually worked was that space after "&", so ````& :visited```` not ````&:visited````

Comment: How do we specify the color for when the icon is not hovered?